# Syntax error at position 7: no viable alternative at input 'table'

Tags: cassandra

Environment:

```
Cassandra and CLI version is 1.2.12
OS                           Windows7 Enterprise, 64 Bit.
```

ran `cassendra-cli.bat`, When running the create table command I get following:

> [default@unknown] create table us(name varchar); Syntax error at
>   position 7: no viable alternative at input 'table'

Any idea why its throwing error ?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the older CLI client. This is pre-CQL and uses the Thrit API. If you want to use that client then check out the [older docs](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli). The general view is that CQL is the way to go though.

To use CQL use the CQLSH client instead.

One thing to note, even in CQL your statement is not valid. You must specify a primary key.

```
create table us(name varchar, primary key (name));
```

Comment: This didn't work; still getting same "no viable alternative at input 'table'"

Comment: Oh I'm being dumb. I've just noticed you are using the older CLI. I will update my answer.

Comment: Also I need the documentation reference to this CLI.

Comment: Now I upgraded to cassendra version 2.0.3 and CLI version is also 2.0.3 but I still get same error.  When I type help; it display list of command options but doesnt display create table command (There is create column command only).

Comment: You did not need to upgrade your Cassandra version. It will make no difference to this error. As mentioned, there are 2 ways of talking to Cassandra. If you want to use CQL then use the CQL client (called CQLSH). You are using the Thrift client which uses different commands.